# Matplotlib: Rotating a patch without it getting skewed due different x and y axis scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate a patch (For example a rectangle) in a plot that has differently scaled axes. For example, the "step size" of the y axis may be 10x that of the x axis. If I rotate a patch in such a coordinate system it will get completely skewed. Of course, this makes sense since the transformation is correct relative to the plot but in my case its undesirable and I want the patches I rotate to keep their shape.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches    
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

r1 = patches.Rectangle((0,0), 20, 200, color="blue", alpha=0.50)
r2 = patches.Rectangle((0,0), 20, 200, color="red",  alpha=0.50)

t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-45) + ax.transData
r2.set_transform(t2)

ax.add_patch(r1)
ax.add_patch(r2)

plt.xlim(-20, 60)
plt.ylim(-100, 300)

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the red rectangle to keep its rectangle shape relative to the screen.

Any I ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like you would want to apply the rotation in physical coordinates (pixels), then transform back to data coordinates. Have a look at [plotting-in-physical-coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html#plotting-in-physical-coordinates).

Comment: ... although the best solution depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. So, *why* do you want this?

Comment: Im working on a plotting tool thats embedded into a pyqt gui. The user is supposed to be able to place down patches and rotate them freely. So while "editing" the patch it should keep its shape.

Comment: Note that "keeping its shape" is rather ambiguous when the axes aren't equal. Suppose you have a rectangle that is 100 in the y direction and 20 in the x direction (both measured in data coordinates). This would look like a square in the example image. If you'd rotate it 90 degrees, how long and wide should it be? And when you rotate 45 degrees, which length and width would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from chat gpt 4 and some linear algebra I was able to get it working like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

r1 = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 20, 200, color="blue", alpha=0.5)
r2 = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 20, 200, color="red", alpha=0.5)


p = 10, 100 # rotate around this point

x_lim = (-20, 60)
y_lim = (-100, 300)
ax.set_xlim(x_lim)
ax.set_ylim(y_lim)

x_range = x_lim[1] - x_lim[0]
y_range = y_lim[1] - y_lim[0]
aspect_ratio = y_range / x_range

move_transform = transforms.Affine2D().translate(-p[0], -p[1])
inverse_move_transform = transforms.Affine2D().translate(p[0], p[1])
inverse_scale_transform = transforms.Affine2D().scale(1, 1 / aspect_ratio)
rotate_transform = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-45)
scale_transform = transforms.Affine2D().scale(1, aspect_ratio)

total_transform = move_transform + inverse_scale_transform + rotate_transform + scale_transform + inverse_move_transform + ax.transData

r2.set_transform(total_transform)

ax.add_patch(r1)
ax.add_patch(r2)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```